# Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении 4

Tags: ссп

В результате резко снижается загрузка наших институтов и заводов (,) и становятся неочевидными перспективы их развития.

Нужна ли запятая, разделяющая простые предложения в составе ССП? Другими словами: является ли здесь **в результате** общим второстепенным членом или второе предложение - это как бы следствие первого и запятая все-таки нужна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Запятую лучше не ставить,** хотя, с точки зрения семантики, решение относительно общего второстепенного члена не кажется очевидным.

Но здесь дело в том, что предложения мало распространенные и **пауза между ними нежелательна.** При наличии же паузы не будет четко обозначена причинно-следственная связь событий.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял: (1) Оба варианта не будут ошибкой, но запятая нежелательна, (2) Даже если убрать общий элемент ("в результате"), то все равно смотри пункт (1)

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь все-таки определяющим является второстепенный член, из-за него не ставится запятая. Спасибо.

Comment: Запятая не ствится в связи с общим второстепенным членом. Но часто возникает вопрос: а точно ли это второстепенный член относится к обоим предложениям, а не только к первому? В данном случае мы считаем, что он действительно общий, и в этом нам помогает интонация, которая связывает два предложения в одну фразу.